# Use &[u8] as key in HashMap

Tags: rust, hashmap

How can I fix this function:

```rust
fn func<'a>(x: &'a HashMap<&[u8], String>) -> Option<&'a String> {
    let k = vec![1, 2, 3];
    let k: &[u8] = &k;
    x.get(&k)
}
```

I receive error

```
error[E0515]: cannot return value referencing local variable `k`
 --> src/lib.rs:6:5
  |
5 |     let k: &[u8] = &k;
  |                    -- `k` is borrowed here
6 |     x.get(&k)
  |     ^^^^^^^^^ returns a value referencing data owned by the current function
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Why* it happens is complicated, but the fix is simple:

```rust
fn func<'a>(x: &'a HashMap<&[u8], String>) -> Option<&'a String> {
    let k = vec![1, 2, 3];
    let k: &[u8] = &k;
    x.get(k)
}
```

Note the removed `&`.

Comment: Why is it complicated?

Comment: "Why" is probably related to this [known bug about lifetime entanglement of key and return value of `HashMap::get`](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/80389)

Answer (score 1):

Simplified version without a second statement for `k`:

```rust
fn func<'a>(x: &'a HashMap<&[u8], String>) -> Option<&'a String> {
    let k = vec![1, 2, 3];
    x.get(&k[..])
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=0ef006c1673d64b2020f57ad18b5bb6a)